# How do I make my bot repeat a message without the command?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know if there's a way that I could make a say command but without the prefix + say.

```
if(msg.content.startsWith("!say")){
  const say = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${msg.content`})
msg.channel.send(say)
```

This is my code, where it appears the "!say"
Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) by spaces and remove the first value (which would be `"!say"`) then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the rest.

```js
if(msg.content.startsWith("!say")){
  const filteredMessage = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  const say = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setDescription(filteredMessage);
  msg.channel.send(say);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try asap

Answer (score -2):

Also you can try using this code which is more simple than Elitezen's code

```js
if(msg.content.startsWith("!say")){
let text = args.join(" ");
const say = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${text}`);
msg.channel.send(say)}
```

Comment: This includes the command. The `.slice(1)` is meant to remove the command.

Comment: @MrMythical, https://imgur.com/a/4UC9zTf

Comment: You probably already sliced it. I don't think the OP did